# Existe outra maneira de acessar o índice de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python

**Quero saber:**

- Existe outra maneira de acessar o índice em questão, onde estou usando no print()?
- Guardo em **'dados'** os respectivos valores, mas por serem de decimais, estou tendo dificuldade em reporta para o usuário.
- A pesar de quase pronto, se possível quero sugestões para eu melhora.

**Segue o script:**

```
print('\n') 
dados = []
for index in range(2):
    print('\n') #   Espaço linha
nome = input('None do Atleta: ')
nome.capitalize()
if nome < '.':
    print('Reenicie o sistema, digitando o nome do atleta')
    break
print('\n') #   E2
distância = input('Distancia do salto: ')
dados.append(distância)

print(f'Atleta: {nome}\n')
print(f'Primeiro salto: {distância[0:2]}')
print(f'Segundo salto: {distância[2:4]}')
print(f'Dados informados: {dados[0:]}')
```

Comment: Tem como colocar uma amostra de dados, ou uma especificação do dados, com que alimente o algoritmo?

Comment: Só para constar que a operação sendo feita não é indexação propriamente dita, mas sim um slicing.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, irei modificar.  Obrigado.

Comment: Daniel, consegue nos dar um exemplo do que será a entrada do programa? E explicar melhor o que deveria ser a condição `if nome < '.'`?

Comment: @Woss, SIM, com certeza. A entrada pede:

Comment: Pede o que? Acho que você não terminou o comentário.

Comment: Esse `break` dentro do `if` dá erro, já que `break` só pode estar dentro de um *loop* (e no caso, não está). Também não está claro o que exatamente vc está tentando fazer, pois a lista `dados` só vai ter um elemento, e ao fazer `distancia[0:2]` vc está acessando pedaços da string que foi digitada. Enfim, está tudo muito confuso...

Comment: @Woss, SIM, com certeza. A entrada pede: o nome do atleta, posteriormente, if o nome for menor que **'.'** ele vai parar. Ou seja, caso o usuario não digite o nome do atleta, não tem continuidade. Essa foi maneira que pensei pra essa situação. No processamento, o pg ira pega as notas digitadas, como por ex, 8.4, ou 3.6 (decimais) e coloca-los em **dados**, daí tenho que retorna esses valores de nota pro usuario como tá ali no print, posteriormente, informa: primeira nota: 3.4; segunda nota: 8.6, assim por diante.

Comment: @DanielAlvesdeBarros, dá uma olhada [nesse print](https://imgur.com/a/Vwn6Y2B). Veja que modifiquei o recuo do código e troquei `if nome < '.':` por `if nome.strip() == "":` . Mas ainda estou com dificuldades de entender o que está querendo fazer, pois por mim eu faria um  dicionário de saltos e cada salto o trataria como um valor numérico.

Comment: "*caso o usuario não digite o nome do atleta*" - testar se o nome é menor que `.` **não** serve para isso, se eu digitar `;` será considerado maior que `.`, por exemplo. Você teria que testar se o nome é vazio, como já sugerido pelo Augusto acima.

Comment: E não faz sentido digitar todas as notas de uma vez e guardar tudo na mesma string para depois pegar pedaços dela, o melhor é ter uma lista de notas (novamente, como já sugerido)

Comment: @AugustoVasques, inicialmente coloquei essa condição pra nome como 'if nome == ()', mas obviamente, como já mencionado por vos, não dá. Obrigado pelo método puro enviado 'strip'/faixa colocado partilhado. Eu poderia fazer sim com dicio, no entanto, trata-se de um questão. Mas não sei se será possivel, já que estou com imensa dificuldade de achar o indice da lista, ex 'print(f'Primeiro salto {distancia[0:2]}'). No entanto por se trata de decimais fica difícil

Comment: @hkotsubo, (nome de usuário interessante esse seu rsrs), meu caro, obrigado. Já reportei sua observação pro program e lhe classifiquei.

Comment: Pelo que entendi você está querendo fazer algo assim: https://ideone.com/mUAfIU